az monitor diagnostic-settings create Azure CLI Command gives an error when run from GitBash Terminal
I'm attempting to execute a command in GitBash Terminal to create Diagnostics Settings for an Azure Storage account. This command runs successfully when executed directly in Azure CLI.
Steps taken:
Azure Login:
az login
Set Subscription:
az account set --subscription xxxxxxxxxxxxx
Subscription set to [Subscription ID].
Command Used:
az monitor diagnostic-settings create --resource /subscriptions/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555/resourceGroups/resource-jumpbox/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/teststorage   --name cafsmpso-diagnostics  --metrics '[{"category": "AllMetrics","enabled": true}]'  --event-hub-rule /subscriptions/11111111-2222-3333-4444-555555555555/resourceGroups/eventhub-recsourcegroup/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/eventhub/authorizationrules/RootManageSharedAccessKey  --event-hub csc-logi-prd-neu-eventhub-ns

Error Encountered:
?[91musage error: --resource ID | --resource NAME --resource-group NAME --resource-type TYPE [--resource-parent PARENT] [--resource-namespace NAMESPACE]?[0m
Please let me know what I am missing here. This is part of a bash script I am writting so should be able to excute the bash script using GitBash Terminal.
This exact command create the diasnostics settings when directly used in Azure CLI

The error shows that the command is expecting few more arguments along with the --resource parameter. Provide the other parameters like --resourcetypeetc to make it worked.
Refer az monitor diagnostic-settings create parameters in MS Doc.
I have tried to execute the similar command as you in git environment and was able to perform it successfully as shown.
az monitor diagnostic-settings create --name cafsmpso-diagnostics --resource-group xxx --resource-type Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts --resource storenewjh --metrics "[{\"category\":\"AllMetrics\",\"enabled\":true}]" --event-hub-rule /subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxxx/providers/Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/newwsj/authorizationrules/RootManageSharedAccessKey --event-hub eventshub


Alternatively, try listing out the authorization rules with the below command to verify if it existed.
az eventhubs eventhub authorization-rule list --resource-group xxxx --namespace-name newwsj --eventhub-name eventshub


Or else instead of using event hub resource for logs storage, use storage or workspace which is an efficient and easy way as detailed below.
az monitor diagnostic-settings create --name cafsmpso-diagnostics --resource-group xxxx --resource-type Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts --resource storenewjh --metrics '[{"category": "AllMetrics","enabled": true}]' --storage-account storenewjh


